# Class variable and instance variable question in Python

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables

When I have this class, the variable 'value' is class variable.

```
class Hello:
    value = 10
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init'
```

I have an object 'h' and I could get the same value of '10' both for Hello.value and h.value.

```
h = Hello()
print Hello.value
print h.value
```

When I  run this command,

```
h.value = 20
```

I get value '10', and '20', when I run them.

```
print Hello.value
print h.value
```

Why is this?

- Q1 : Why 'print h.value' prints out the value of Hello.value, not raise an error?
- Q2 : Does h.value = 20 introduce a new variable  similar to 'self.value = 20'?
- Q3 : Is there a way to prevent creating an instance variable (or prevent running code 'h.value = 20')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how attribute lookup works in Python:

1. If an attribute can't be found in the dictionary of an instance, it is looked up in the dictionary of its class, and if it can't be found there, also in the dictionaries of the base classes.
2. If you assign to an instance attribute, this will always only affect the instance -- i.e. update the attribute if it already exists in the instance or create it in the instance's dictionary if not.

If you don't like this behaviour, you can overwrite the `__setattr__()` method to do whatever you like -- for example throwing an error if you don't want to allow the creation of instance attributes.  The latter can also be achieved by adding `__slots__ = []` to the class.

Answer (score 4):

If Python looks up `o.attr`, it first checks the object instance, then its class, then the base class, and so on. It does so both for methods and data attributes (i.e. there is no distinction between data and code attributes).

On assignment, the value always gets assigned to the instance. So

- A1. Because it falls back to the
  class (which it must, because methods
  wouldn't work otherwise)
- A2. Yes, it does.
- A3. You can define a `__setattr__`
  method that raises an exception.